# Is it possible to install python3.9-dev on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: python

I've been googling a bit, but not finding anything useful.

Comment: The `python3.9-dev` package is only available for Ubuntu 20.04 (not 22.04). 22.04 uses Python 3.10. Changing the system-provided Python version is **likely** to break your system. Consider using a VM of Ubuntu 20.04, or install Python 3.9 using a different method (not apt, not deb packages).

Comment: What is available can be seen with https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3.9-dev&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all which shows it only for *focal* or 20.04..  CLI commands can also be used to show the same detail (*regardless of what release you're using too & even show results for ESM*)